# Best json library for Python 2.2 or earlier?

Tags: python, json

A platform I am working on only supports python 2.2.  I need to process some simple JSON input. JSON wasn't part of the standard library in version 2.2 and simpleJSON requires a later version as well. What are my options?  Thanks!

Comment: ... 2.2? Seriously? I'd find someone else...

Comment: What does your ISP have anything to do with what version of python you're running.

Comment: Move to Linode (http://www.linode.com).

Comment: Get a new hosting provider. From [this rather unofficial list](http://deron.meranda.us/python/comparing_json_modules/), it looks like the common Python JSON modules require at least 2.3 and most require newer than that.

Comment: A gas station near me only sells leaded gas.  What are my options?  *use a different gas station*

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean ISP, as most correctly interpreted, I meant my hosting provider.  Going to a new one is a longer term solution, but not in the short run.

Comment: Forget the part about the ISP (although I totally agree). Sometimes, people are locked in because of other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.2 is [nine years old](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/) and there's a [security issue](http://www.python.org/news/security/PSF-2005-001/) that ships with 2.2 that they don't distribute a compiled fix for (there's a patch but not a new 2.2 release to cover it).  Python 2.2 is unsupported and outdated, and Python [comes with a `json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) as of 2.6.  Your best bet is to find a provider that doesn't use old, insecure, and unsupported pieces of software.

Comment: That's not a solution. I have to use 2.2 to work on legacy hardware platforms where upgrading would cause severe downtime and complicated compatibility issues with legacy code, not to mention that the embedded systems are now owned by someone else.

Comment: you would be surprised but WebLogic uses Jython version 2.2.1 in 2015, and to upgrade is a headache, especially considering this script has to work on many separate installations of WebLogic where one has to go through bureaucratic channels to make such changes to client's system

Answer (score 1):

@brice You can use old release of simplejson python library with weblogic.
If beahome is /home/oracle/middleware then commands will be:

```
curl -o /tmp/python2.2.zip -LJO https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/archive/python2.2.zip
unzip /tmp/python2.2.zip -d /tmp/python2.2
cp -R /tmp/python2.2/simplejson-python2.2/simplejson /home/oracle/middleware/oracle_common/common/wlst
```